# Conditional heading color using uib-accordion

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular-ui with my angularjs application. I have an accordion (uib-accordion) element on my page. Its content, name and state (opened/closed) are bind to an array in the controller.

I want to achieve the following behavior: when the tab is closed, the heading should be gray. When it is opened, it should be another color. How can I do that, based on the value of filter.isOpened? I tried with ng-class something like:

```
 ng-class="{'panel-blue-heading': filter.isOpened}"
```

but I did not manage to do it. Below is a simple fiddle, maybe it helps.
Thanks!

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.filtersInfo = [{
    filterParams: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    filterName: "testFilter",
    isOpened: true
  }];
}]);
```

```css
.panel-default {
  border: 0;
}

.panel-group {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 5px;
}

.panel-default >.panel-heading {
  color: black;
}

.panel-blue-heading >.panel-heading {
  background-color: #42c6eb;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl" class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="filter in filtersInfo">
      <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <div is-open="filter.isOpened" uib-accordion-group              class="panel-default">
          <uib-accordion-heading>
            {{ filter.filterName }}
          </uib-accordion-heading>

          <div>
            ...MY CONTENT...
          </div
        </div>
      </uib-accordion>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it `filter.isOpen` or `filter.isOpened`? Please make sure you don't have a typo.

Comment: @Izagkaretos, it was a typo in the fiddle, I deleted some things because the actual content is bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime" ng-class="{'opened': filter.isOpened}" id="my-accordion">
```

Then in your CSS, target the `.panel-heading` that is created by the directive:

```
#my-accordion.opened .panel-heading {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I add the ID so as not affect any other panel headings that were not intended to have a blue background.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.filtersInfo = [{
    filterParams: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    filterName: "testFilter",
    isOpened: true
  }];
}]);
```

```css
#my-accordion.opened .panel-heading {
  background-color: blue;
}

.panel-default {
  border: 0;
}

.panel-group {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 5px;
}

.panel-default >.panel-heading {
  color: black;
}

.panel-blue-heading >.panel-heading {
  background-color: #42c6eb;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl" class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="filter in filtersInfo">
      <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime" ng-class="{'opened': filter.isOpened}" id="my-accordion">
        <div is-open="filter.isOpened" uib-accordion-group              class="panel-default">
          <uib-accordion-heading>
            {{ filter.filterName }}
          </uib-accordion-heading>

          <div>
            ...MY CONTENT...
          </div
        </div>
      </uib-accordion>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was very close. Thank you for the solution, it works perfectly.